# What CSS/JS/HTML/XML plugin(s) do you use in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, eclipse

I'm looking for a good plugin for doing web front end work in Eclipse. I don't want something that completely takes over eclipse, or something that has masses of dependencies that need to be updated all the time, or something that is geared towards a particular server-side platform, or something that costs a heap.

Is there something light-weight out there that hits the sweet spot?

I tried aptana - found it took over my whole eclipse environment and put news feeds and other rubbish all over the place.

I then tried installing a subset of the aptana jar's and ended up pretty happy with the result.

Here's what I have in my plugins directory:

> com.aptana.ide.core_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.snippets_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.core.ui_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.debug.core_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.editor.css_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.editor.html_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.editor.js_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.editors_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.editors.codeassist_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.epl_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.io.file_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.jface.text.source_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.lexer_1.1.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.libraries_1.2.0.18696
>   com.aptana.ide.libraries.jetty_1.2.0.018852
>   com.aptana.ide.logging_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.parsing_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.search.epl_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.server_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.server.core_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.server.jetty_1.2.0.018852.jar
>   com.aptana.ide.server.ui_1.2.0.018852.jar

..and in the features:

> com.aptana.ide.feature.editor.css_1.2.0.018852
>   com.aptana.ide.feature.editors_1.2.0.018852
>   com.aptana.ide.feature.editor.html_1.2.0.018852
>   com.aptana.ide.feature.editor.js_1.2.0.018852

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I use the standalone community version of Aptana for that sort of thing, as I don't really use Eclipse for anything much else these days.

There is an Eclipse plugin version of Aptana, info available here: http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration

Update: New link to get this plugin:
http://aptana.org/products/studio3/download

Comment: The info page has moved here: http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration

Comment: That link now redirects to AppCelerator.  Was Aptana's web/ruby/html5 team absorbed into appcelerator's javascript-all-the-things titanium team?

Answer (score 9):

This is a very old initial question but since it's still very visible in Google I thought I'd update the answer for 2018 for anyone who happens to be wondering the same. Right now, the best editor for all the web languages is [CodeMix](https://www.genuitec.com/products/codemix/codemix-journey/). You can read about it at the link provided or install it from the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codemix).

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you need the [Web Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)

Update:  In latest 2016 Eclipse Neon, go to HELP -> Install Software and search for Eclipse Web Developer tools.  For some reason it's hard to find them from the Marketplace.

[image: help install software]

[image: web developer tools]

Comment: edited this answer because Eclipse team has made it hard to find this project through a combination of misbegotten changes to Eclipse. The new marketplace has a terrible semantic understanding, and zero popularity/relevance for common searches like "web developer"

Answer (score 5):

You may like:

- JSEclipse plugin ([update site](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/jseclipse/autoinstall)) originally developed by Interactonline, later acquired by Adobe
- Eclipse Web Tools Platform Project ([update site](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/))

Answer (score 2):

It depends - for JS and CSS I use  standard Webtools plugin. But for HTML and XML I think Aptana made great fork - autoformatting in HTML really helps a lot. I use Eclipse, but download Aptana as plugin and use only some of it's feautures.

Also Aptana JS editor gives your possibility to use code complete and doc for most popular JS frameworks such as jQuery or Ext.

Answer (score 1):

I use in my company the [Amateras HTML Editor](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor). It is the base for other more advanced editors for editing JSF, Struts, UML, XML, ...). It is straightforward, just a plugin, and does the necessary jobs pretty well. Comes with a source editor (with completion) and a preview that works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Eclipse Juno has great HTML/CSS/XML/JS editors, with the PDT a good plugin for PHP